# Close and Adjusted Close in Interactive Brokers API and Yahoo Finance

Tags: time-series, market-data, interactive-brokers, yahoofinance, ohlc

On [Interactive Broker's TWS API manual](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_bars.html#hd_what_to_show), there are several historical data types to choose from.

Which IB TWS data type's `Close` value corresponds to

1. Close
2. Adjusted Close

in Yahoo Finance?

Answer (score 2):

On the page you link:

> TRADES data is adjusted for splits, but not dividends
>
> ADJUSTED_LAST data is adjusted for splits and dividends. Requires TWS 967+.

So to get adjusted close, request `ADJUSTED_LAST` and use the Close field. To get the unadjusted close, request `TRADES` and use the Close field.